# Delpoy sharepoint app project and solution

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

When I created a solution of sharepoint MVC app, it is deployed and working fine. This is a test purpose. However when I created a SP MVC app project in an existing solution, am not able to deploy the app. What all things I need to consider to deploy SP app project from a solution?

Comment: How you are doing solution? Using visual studio?

Comment: Have you specified "site url" property in project settings? do you get any errors during deployment?

Comment: Associated web project automatically created and referred. When tried to deply I got the error : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84219/sharepoint-app-deployment-error-failed-to-install-app-for-sharepoint?noredirect=1#comment80713_84219

Comment: According to stack trace there is a problem with one of the modules.

Comment: which module? associated web project? But I haven't changed anything from default.

Comment: Maybe you have some other modules? If not then could you please post associated web project module?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42486/discussion-between-praveen-prasannan-and-yevgeniy-chernobrivets)